# Angular 5-Difference between Importing life cycle hook from metadata and core

Tags: angular

is there any difference between below two imports-

1. `import { OnInit } from '@angular/core/src/metadata/lifecycle_hooks';`
2. `import { onInit} from '@angular/core';`

Answer (score 0):

Use `@angular/core`.

`'@angular/core/src/metadata/lifecycle_hooks'` is not the standard way to do it although that is where it is sourced from anyway.

Comment: You are not supposed to import files from `src/` of 3rd-party packages. They are private by convention. The Angular team doesn't consider changes of the file structure or the API inside `src/` as breaking, so your code might break with any update without any notice, while files outside `src/` are considered public API and the Angular team is very careful to not cause breaking changes there and if they think they can't avoid it, the change the Angular version number to indicate the breaking change and list it in the CHANGELOG.md

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Thanks for the detailed explanation.